# load a page inside page jquery div before posting form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have the jquery code below which posts a form with checkboxes and updates the results according to the users choices. All works fine but I would like to automatically load the page first so that the default results are returned when the users visits the page, also I would like it if the user clicked the one of the results and clicked back that it would return the previous results.

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".remember_cb").click(function () {
        var action = $("#criteria").attr('action');
        var form_data = $('#criteria').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: form_data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loading").fadeIn('fast');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#exercise_list').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the most "proper" solution, but you could put the code of the selector into a seperate function.

Then you could call the function in the document.ready section and also put it into the selector. This way it'll load once the page is opened and then every time the user clicks on it.

Also I'm not quite sure what your return false is doing, since it's in the document ready section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ahatius , I managed to get it to work with the following code at the top of the code inside the document ready section.  $('#exercise_list').load('/data.php').fadeIn('slow');